# Objective-c++ symbol not found strangeness

Tags: header, objective-c++, symbol-not-found

hej.h

```
void hej();
```

hej.m

```
void hej(){}
```

main.mm

```
#import "hej.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

This gives me:

"hej()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
symbol(s) not found

If I rename main.mm to main.m (single m), or hej.m to mm or cpp, then it works. (Though none of those "solutions" are preferable. Imagine you want to use a c-lib in a objc++ environment - you wouldn't wanna change the entire lib, maybe even couldn't, and you need to use it in objc++.)

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Is Objective-C++ the front-end to the GNU Compiler Collection which can compile source files which use a combination of C++ and Objective-C syntax?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When compiled in a C file (`*.c, *.m`), the declaration `void hej()` generates a linker reference to a C function named `_hej`. When compiled in a C++ file (`*.cc, *.mm,` etc.), the declaration generates a linker reference to a C++ 'mangled name', that includes in it a description of the arguments. (This is done to support function overloading, e.g. to differentiate `void hej(int)` from `void hej(char*)`). hej.m always creates the C name. When main.mm references the C++ name, it won't be found.

To resolve, ensure main.mm looks for a C name, not a C++ one. If you control hej.h, it's common to add something like the following, which would work when hej.h is included in either a C or a C++ file:

```
/* hej.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void hej();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you do not own hej.h, you could do the following in main.mm instead:

```
extern "C" {
#import "hej.h"
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```