# iphone,where do i declare a global method that can called in all the classes

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How can i write a global method that can be called anywhere in my iPhone App
Can any one Help Please....

Answer (score 3):

You can write global functions (not part of a class) wherever you like. Just add the declaration where you use it (i.e. include a header file).

For example:

*File globalfunctions.h*

```
void doCoolStuff();
```

*File globalfunctions.c*

```
#include "globalfunctions.h"
void doCoolStuff()
{

}
```

and where you use it use

```
#include "globalfunctions.h" // or
#import "globalfunctions.h"
```

Comment: Eiko's answer works, but keep in mind that if you want this to work on an iPhone, then you must name your file `globalfunctions.mm` not **.c** (in addition to of course, the .h file) or you will have compilation errors. Just did this last night.

Comment: The correct file ending will only depend on what kind of language you are using. If ObjC, use '.m', if Obj-C++, use '.mm'. You will get away if '.c' if you don't use any Obj-C-ish things.

Comment: Oh yeah, true. I was using some ObjC classes and couldn't compile until I made the extension `.mm`. But I also learned that, again, depending on if you are using Obj-Cish things or not you may need to reference this thread to modify your `.h` file to link properly. I just had trouble linking mine when I did this. And this solution worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362695/objective-c-symbol-not-found-strangeness

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use the Singleton Class to contain global data and methods for your iphone application.  Here are 2 good references: [Singleton Tutorial](http://theappleblog.com/2010/05/18/iphone-dev-sessions-using-singletons/), [Singleton Pattern](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)